# Adding Album Art using python in mp3 metadata

Tags: python, mp3, metadata, id3, artwork

The code below doesnt seem to update the artwork of the mp3 file.

**Code:-**

```
#Editing the MetaData
tag = eyeD3.Tag()
print tag.link('location') //Returns 1
tag.setVersion([2,3,0])
print tag.addImage(0x08,'artwork.jpg') //Return None (Its sure that file is present)
print tag.update()  //Returns 1
```

The values returned by the function are correct but then also the metadata is not getting updated.

> What can be the possible reasons?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you embed album art into an MP3 using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409949/how-do-you-embed-album-art-into-an-mp3-using-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're specifically referring to adding images to an MP3 using the eyeD3 module. I've only used the CLI version of eyeD3 so I may be wrong, but you don't seem to be passing a type parameter to the addImage method. I don't remember being able to get it to work without passing a type.

> --add-image=IMG_PATH:TYPE[:DESCRIPTION]
>                           Add an image to the tag.  The description and type
>                           optional, but when used, both ':' delimiters must be
>                           present.  The type MUST be an string that corresponds
>                           to one given with --list-image-types. If the IMG_PATH
>                           value is empty the APIC frame with TYPE is removed.

http://eyed3.nicfit.net/