# Does anyone have good examples of using mutagen to write to files?

Tags: python, mutagen

Just as the title asks — does anyone have a good example of using the [Mutagen Python ID3 library](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to write to `.mp3` files?

I'm looking, in particular, to add disc/track number information, but examples editing the title and artist would be helpful as well.

Cheers,
/YGA

Comment: Is there some problem with the Mutagen tutorial? http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/wiki/Tutorial

Answer (score 27):

Taken from a script I made a while ago for embedding lyrics into MP3 files:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577138-embed-lyrics-into-mp3-files-using-mutagen-uslt-tag/

The relevant part is:

```python
from mutagen.id3 import ID3NoHeaderError
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, TIT2, TALB, TPE1, TPE2, COMM, TCOM, TCON, TDRC, TRCK

# Read the ID3 tag or create one if not present
try: 
    tags = ID3(fname)
except ID3NoHeaderError:
    print("Adding ID3 header")
    tags = ID3()

tags["TIT2"] = TIT2(encoding=3, text=title)
tags["TALB"] = TALB(encoding=3, text=u'mutagen Album Name')
tags["TPE2"] = TPE2(encoding=3, text=u'mutagen Band')
tags["COMM"] = COMM(encoding=3, lang=u'eng', desc='desc', text=u'mutagen comment')
tags["TPE1"] = TPE1(encoding=3, text=u'mutagen Artist')
tags["TCOM"] = TCOM(encoding=3, text=u'mutagen Composer')
tags["TCON"] = TCON(encoding=3, text=u'mutagen Genre')
tags["TDRC"] = TDRC(encoding=3, text=u'2010')
tags["TRCK"] = TRCK(encoding=3, text=u'track_number')

tags.save(fname)
```

#### See also:

- https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/id3.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2_frame_specification

Comment: I wonder if you are supposed to close file objects like `ID3`.

Comment: The [docs](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/id3.html) don't mention anything resembling a `close()` method therefore I'd assume `save()` is all you need. You can look at the source if you need more details: https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen

Comment: The code uses complicated logic for maintaining the context; hard to say from the code whether it stores a file name or an open file descriptor: https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen/blob/6298fa63e619f3d31dcc79c72898489f57ad2b3e/mutagen/_util.py#L207
I would hope for the former, i.e. the file is opened every time on load/save. I also edited thousands of files in a loop without a crash, so that may be fine (although I don’t know what the limit is for file descriptors per process in my system).

Comment: I'm assuming the package is following the least surprise principle. If you run into a bottleneck or a limitation then consider filling an issue on github so that the author can respond.

Answer (score 6):

Did you check out the examples on the web. Some of these should help you.

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/22/parsing-id3-tags-from-mp3s-using-python/

[Edit:]

Mutagen tutorial is pretty good, hence did not add more information.
dir() provides most of the details.

For setting album cover to mp3 using mutagen

- [How do you embed album art into an MP3 using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409949/how-do-you-embed-album-art-into-an-mp3-using-python)

Embedding lyrics using mutagen

- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577138-embed-lyrics-into-mp3-files-using-mutagen-uslt-fra/

An example

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
import mutagen.id3

filename = 'xxx.mp3'

# Example which shows how to automatically add tags to an MP3 using EasyID3

mp3file = MP3(filename, ID3=EasyID3)

try:
    mp3file.add_tags(ID3=EasyID3)
except mutagen.id3.error:
    print("has tags")

mp3file['title'] = 'Newly tagged'
mp3file.save()
print(mp3file.pprint())
```

Answer (score 6):

An easy way to do it:

```
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
audio = EasyID3(mp3_filename_import)
audio['title'] = "Title"
audio['artist'] = "Artist"
audio['album'] = "Album"
audio['composer'] = "" # empty
audio.save()
```

If the tags don't appear, then change the last line to:

```
audio.save(v2_version=3)
```