# What's the simplest python lib for edit mp3's album and artist?

Tags: python, mp3

What's the simplest python lib for edit mp3 album and artist?

I mean, just get and set the strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's *the simplest*, but one Python-centric audio tagging library I've heard about many times is [Mutagen](http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/).

Comment: It's really missing documentation. But I found that with shell-script it's easiest.

Answer (score 1):

Good review at http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/22/parsing-id3-tags-from-mp3s-using-python/

Gist of it: eyeD3 (with a quick hack to install on Windows) or mutagen (without much documentation). Examples of each in action: [How do you embed album art into an MP3 using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409949/how-do-you-embed-album-art-into-an-mp3-using-python)

There is also a package at https://github.com/disko/bp.tagging which wraps mutagen - this may help you figure it out.