# Python read MP3 cover file

Tags: python-3.x, mp3, cover, mutagen, apic

I am trying to read the cover from an MP3 file with the following code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from io import BytesIO
import mutagen
from mutagen.id3 import APIC

root = tk.Tk()
image_bytes = mutagen.File('/Users/id3-sample.mp3')['APIC:'].data 
image_stream = BytesIO(image_bytes)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image_stream))
tk.Label(root, image = img).pack()
```

But I get the following error message:

```
File  "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mutagen/_util.py", line 536, in __getitem__
return self.__dict[key]
builtins.KeyError: 'APIC:'
```

Comment: The `:` at the end of `APIC:` should probably not be there....

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mutagen's File, Picture classes.
Checkout this answer by [foosion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7282712/7977581).

Answer (score 0):

The exception type `KeyError` you got, is raised by the `__getitem__` method of an object of type `dict` when, using the syntax `dictionary[key]`, you try to access for reading the value of a key that is not stored in the dictionary.

In your code, as pointed out by @Thierry Lathuille in the comments, you are doing that mistake. You are trying to access for reading the value of the key `APIC:` which is not stored into the object of type `mutagen.File` supporting attribute retrieval through the `__getitem__` method (as dictionaries does). The correct key should be `APIC`.

```
...
image_bytes = mutagen.File('/Users/id3-sample.mp3')['APIC'].data 
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have checked the mp3 file and found the APIC key:   Ihttp://www.stagetwo.euageTwo AlbumTCON52TIT2Test TitelTPE1Sick^TRCK01TPE2 StageTwoTPOS1TDRC2013COMMXXXBeispiel KommentarTCOMSick^TOPENiemandWXXXhttp://www.stagetwo.euAPICFimage/jpegstagetwo-logo.jpgˇÿˇ‡JFIFˇ˛*ˇ‚ICC_PROFILElcmsmntrRGB XYZ ‹)9acspAPPLˆ÷”-lcms
desc¸^cprt\wtpthbkpt|

Comment: Well, technically speaking it was an answer, not a comment and you should accept it. Anyway you're welcome! Moreover I would advise you not to post data, like you did in your comment. If you have a newer different question do not post it in comments. Thanks