# How do I extract album art using pydub

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pydub

I want to extract album art from a song and embed it back to the song after conversion,         using **Pydub**. Is it possible can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

At it's core, Pydub operates on raw audio data (samples). It provides constructors that decode non-raw audio files (via ffmpeg) for convenience, but unless you can do it using ffmpeg flags, I don't think so. (I wrote the vast majority of pydub, and I've never done it =P )

There *is* good news though! I think [mutagen](https://mutagen.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) can help you :)

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409949/how-do-you-embed-album-art-into-an-mp3-using-python)

And if you wanted to do audio processing with pydub, just use `audio_segment.export()`, and then use mutagen to set the album artwork :)