# Running into problems setting cover art for MP4 files using Python and Mutagen

Tags: python, mp3, mp4, mutagen

Following multiple suggestions from other StackOverflow questions and the mutagen documentation, I was able to come up with code to get and set every ID3 tag in both MP3 and MP4 files.  The issue I have is with setting the cover art for M4B files.

I have reproduced the code exactly like it is laid out in this answer:

[Embedding album cover in MP4 file using Mutagen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897801/embedding-album-cover-in-mp4-file-using-mutagen)

But I am still receiving errors when I attempt to run the code.  If I run the code with the 'albumart' value by itself I receive the error:

```
MP4file.tags['covr'] = albumart
```

> Exception has occurred: TypeError
>   can't concat int to bytes

However, if I surround the albumart variable with brackets like is shown in the aforementioned StackOverflow question I get this output:

```
MP4file.tags['covr'] = [albumart]
```

> Exception has occurred: struct.error
>   required argument is not an integer

Here is the function in it's entirety.  The MP3 section works without any problems.

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from mutagen.mp4 import MP4, MP4Cover


def set_cover(filename, cover):
    r = requests.get(cover)
    with open('C:/temp/cover.jpg', 'wb') as q:
        q.write(r.content)
    if(filename.endswith(".mp3")):
        MP3file = MP3(filename, ID3=ID3)
        if cover.endswith('.jpg') or cover.endswith('.jpeg'):
            mime = 'image/jpg'
        else:
            mime = 'image/png'
        with open('C:/temp/cover.jpg', 'rb') as albumart: 
            MP3file.tags.add(APIC(encoding=3, mime=mime, type=3, desc=u'Cover', data=albumart.read()))
        MP3file.save(filename)
    else:
        MP4file = MP4(filename)
        if cover.endswith('.jpg') or cover.endswith('.jpeg'):
            cover_format = 'MP4Cover.FORMAT_JPEG'
        else:
            cover_format = 'MP4Cover.FORMAT_PNG'
        with open('C:/temp/cover.jpg', 'rb') as f:
            albumart = MP4Cover(f.read(), imageformat=cover_format)
        MP4file.tags['covr'] = [albumart]
```

I have been trying to figure out what I am doing wrong for two days now.  If anyone can help me spot the problem I would be in your debt.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the source code of `mutagen` at the location where the exception is being raised I've found the following lines:

```
 def __render_cover(self, key, value):
        ...
        for cover in value:
            try:
                imageformat = cover.imageformat
            except AttributeError:
                imageformat = MP4Cover.FORMAT_JPEG
            ...
            Atom.render(b"data", struct.pack(">2I", imageformat, 0) + cover))
        ...
```

There `key` is the name for the cover tag and `value` is the data read from the image, wrapped into an `MP4Cover` object. Well, it turns out that if you iterates over an `MP4Cover` object, as the above code does, the iteration yields one byte of the image per iteration as `int`.

Moreover, in Python version 3+, `struct.pack` returns an object of type `bytes`. I think the `cover` argument was intended to be the collection of bytes taken from the cover image.

In the code you've given above the bytes of the cover image are wrapped inside an object of type `MP4Cover` that cannot be added to `bytes` as done in the second argument of `Atom.render`.

To avoid having to edit or patch the `mutagen` library source code, the trick is converting the 'MP4Cover' object to `bytes` and wrapping the result inside a collection as shown below.

```
import requests
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from mutagen.mp4 import MP4, MP4Cover


def set_cover(filename, cover):
    r = requests.get(cover)
    with open('C:/temp/cover.jpg', 'wb') as q:
        q.write(r.content)
    if(filename.endswith(".mp3")):
        MP3file = MP3(filename, ID3=ID3)
        if cover.endswith('.jpg') or cover.endswith('.jpeg'):
            mime = 'image/jpg'
        else:
            mime = 'image/png'
        with open('C:/temp/cover.jpg', 'rb') as albumart: 
            MP3file.tags.add(APIC(encoding=3, mime=mime, type=3, desc=u'Cover', data=albumart.read()))
        MP3file.save(filename)
    else:
        MP4file = MP4(filename)
        if cover.endswith('.jpg') or cover.endswith('.jpeg'):
            cover_format = 'MP4Cover.FORMAT_JPEG'
        else:
            cover_format = 'MP4Cover.FORMAT_PNG'
        with open('C:/temp/cover.jpg', 'rb') as f:
            albumart = MP4Cover(f.read(), imageformat=cover_format)
        MP4file.tags['covr'] = [bytes(albumart)]
        MP4file.save(filename)
```

I've also added `MP4file.save(filename)` as the last line of the code to persists the changes done to the file.

Comment: This is correct. For anyone who is having trouble understanding, by adding the square brackets around `bytes(albumart)` you're now saving a list to `MP4file.tags['covr']` which also means your can have more than one image in there.

Comment: This solution does not work for me. The error I get from it is `bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: @hello Has your  local copy of the mutagen library the same version as the one discussed in the question above? And what about the version of your Python interpreter? If your use case is as the one in the answer, maybe something in Python or in the mutagen library has changed. This answer is almost one year old and may refere to outdated software versions.

Comment: This does work for me, though I *believe* the workaround results in the `cover_format` not being recognized and written correctly to the file. I also don't think the lines that assign the `cover_format` should have single quotes, but I don't think that's the issue.